# How can I write a list of tuples to a csv file where the first element of the tuple is a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a list of tuples in the form:

```
data = [({1: 0.1723, 2: 0.890, 3: 1.0}, 'a'),
        ({1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.667}, 'b'),
        ({1: 0.223, 2: 0.336, 3: 1.0}, 'b')]
```

The second element of each tuple is simply a string.

How can I write it to a csv file so that the contiguous columns correspond to each element?

i.e.: for `data[1]`: `col1 = 0.1723`, `col2 = 0.890`, `col3 = 1.0`, `col4 = 'a'`?

Comment: The keys won't be contiguous as `dict` is not ordered.

Comment: @PeterWood yes, but you can always sort the keys.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The order of the elements in the dictionary must be maintained and should be consistent throughout the file.

Comment: you mean that if you put `{3: 1.0, 1: 0.223, 2: 0.336}` it is different from `{1: 0.223, 2: 0.336, 3: 1.0}` ? are the keys determining the order? it better be, or what you're asking is impossible with the current input data.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the keys here are determining the order. For instance, if the first row of file contains data in the order col1 : 1.0, col2: 0.223, col3: 0.336, col4: 'b' and the second and the third rows too should have the same ordering, ie. col1: 0.667, col2: 0.0, col3: 1.0, col4: 'b' for the second element of the list.

Comment: okay then you can check my solution. I still wonder why you create a dictionary with keys to order when you can create a simple list... but whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a generator expression to generate all rows at once, which come in 2 parts.

- sorted list of values of your dictionaries according to keys
- single-element list of the string

this code:

```
import csv

data = [({1: 0.1723, 2: 0.890, 3: 1.0}, 'a'),
        ({1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.667}, 'b'),
        ({1: 0.223, 2: 0.336, 3: 1.0}, 'b')]

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:  # python 2: just: ,"wb")
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerows([v for _,v in sorted(d.items())] + [s] for d,s in data)
```

creates the following file:

```
0.1723,0.89,1.0,a
0.0,1.0,0.667,b
0.223,0.336,1.0,b
```

`for d,s in data` is just a nice way to unpack the dictionary (first item) and the value (second item). And the `csv` module converts floats & integers to string, no need to bother for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as follows:

```
import csv

data = [({1: 0.1723, 2: 0.890, 3: 1.0}, 'a'), ({1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.667}, 'b'), ({1: 0.223, 2: 0.336, 3: 1.0}, 'b')]
rows = []
for the_dict, the_char in data:
    row = []
    # get values from dictionary and add it to row
    for x in the_dict.values():
        row.append(x)
    # add char
    row.append(the_char)
    # ad row to rows list
    rows.append(row)

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
import csv

data = [({1: 0.1723, 2: 0.890, 3: 1.0}, 'a'),
        ({1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.667}, 'b'),
        ({1: 0.223, 2: 0.336, 3: 1.0}, 'b')]

def make_row(elements):
    row = list()
    for obj in elements:
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            row += obj.values()
        else:
            row.append(obj)
    return row

with open('output.csv', 'w') as handle:
    writer = csv.writer(handle)
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(make_row(row))
```